# How to identify specific element with two expect conditions in protractor

Tags: protractor

In my application I want to select specific notification by using it's name **AND** owner name. How can I do that in protractor?
I have added screenshot and I want to select notification "Test Auction1 by Sonal Dalal" from the list.
Second screenshot shows the page code for notification "Test Auction1 by Sonal Dalal"

[image]

[image]

I have tried below code in spec file:

```
Auction.AuctionNotiNewInv.isDisplayed().then(function(){
        Auction.NotificationTitle.get(0).isDisplayed().then(function(){
            Auction.NotificationTitle.count().then(function(Count){
                console.log(Count);
                var NotifTitleCount = Count;
                for(var i=0; i < NotifTitleCount; i++) {
                    Auction.NotificationTitle.get(i).isDisplayed().then(function(){
                        Auction.NotifAuctioneer.isDisplayed().then(function(IsDisplayed){
                        if(IsDisplayed)
                            Auction.NotificationTitle.get(i).click();
                         else
                            console.log('New Auction invitation is not displayed.');

                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And PO file is as below:

```
this.AuctionNotiNewInv = element(by.cssContainingText('.md-subheader-inner','NEW INVITATIONS'));
this.NotificationTitle = element.all(by.cssContainingText('.title.ng-binding',data.AuctionName));
this.NotifAuctioneer = element(by.cssContainingText('.subtitle.ng-binding',data.NewFirstName + ' ' + data.NewLastName));
```

but above code returns me count = 4, as there are other objects on page which has same property of "NotificationTitle" but it's not a part of notification list.
Can anybody suggest me another way to handle this using expect function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter()` method to filter list of elements based on conditions.Try the below locator,

```
var expectedTitle= 'TestAuction1';
var expectedOwner = 'Sonal Dalal';
var notificationElement = element.all(by.repeater("notif in notifSubList")).filter(function(notification){
  var title = notification.element(by.css("span.title")).getText();
  var owner = notification.element(by.css("span.subtitle")).getText();
  return protractor.promise.all([title,owner]).then(function(result){
     return result[0].trim() == expectedTitle && result[1].trim() == expectedOwner;
  })
}).first();
```